# How to bind values of comboboxes of a list view that include them in wpf mvvm view model

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, mvvm

I have 2 class:

```cs
public class Order : ObservableCollection<string>
{    
    public Order()
    {
        Add("1st");
        Add("2nd");
        Add("3rd");
        for (int i=4; i< 100; i++)
        {
            Add($"{i}th");
        }        
    }
}

public class Id : ObservableCollection<string>
{  
    public Id()
    {
        Add("abc12345");
        Add("dce12345");
        //3000 id,...
    } 
}
```

In my xaml:

```xml
<DockPanel Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Height="Auto" Background="LightBlue">
    <DockPanel.Resources>
        <src:Order x:Key="order"/>
        <src:Id x:Key="id"/>
    </DockPanel.Resources>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{StaticResource order}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Order"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="ID">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox
                                Width="200"
                                ItemsSource="{StaticResource id}">
                            </ComboBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</DockPanel>
```

It binded just fine: each row in 100 rows of column "Order" (1st to 99th) in the list box got one combobox that can select the ID. But, how i get each combobox selected value in each row, and bind them to a value (or list) which is created in `public partial class MainWindowViewModel : ObservableObject` instead of `MainWindow`?
I think LINQ is possible but must call from `MainWindow` not `MainViewModel`. But thats meaningless for my control. Any help is appreaciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a classic beginner mistake to inherit from a list type to express a set of data:
You have many car brands, so make `Car` a `List`. (Wrong)
You have many players in a team, so make `Team` a `List`. (Wrong)
You have many products in an order, so make `Order` a `List`. (Wrong)

Composition is usually the better choice than using inheritance.
Most relationships of objects are properly expressed using composition (like real world objects).

If it helps, you only extend a list type if you want to add new features.
For example, a `TemporaryCollection` could track the storing time of its items and remove them after a certain period. ==> New feature ==> extend `List`.
Or if you want to hide the generic type parameter.
For example, by making `List<int>` an `IntegerList`.

In every other case extending from a list type is wrong.

You can also use semantics to check if you are applying correct class design correct.
For example, an order *is not* a number of products. But an oder *has* a number of products.
As well as an order *has* an ID and *has* a timestamp and *has* an associated customer.

If the relationship is *is a* then you must use inheritance.
If the relationship is *has a* then you must use composition:

**SensorType.cs**

```cs
public enum SensorType
{
  Undefined = 0,
  Humidity,
  Temperature
}
```

**Device.cs**

```cs
// If the class serves as a binding source and is a DependencyObject (for example a Control), 
// it MUST implement its properties as dependency properties. 
// If the class serves as a binding source is not a DependencyObject (for example a view model class),
// it MUST implement INotifyPropertyChanged.
public abstract class Device : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  /* Make members static in order to share them across instances */

  private const int LowerPriorityBound = 1;
  private const int UpperPriorityBound = 100;

  // HashSet for fast lookup (Contains() method in our case)
  private static HashSet<int> PriorityValuePool { get; }

  // Use WeakReference and Dictionaries to enable instance tracking without creating a memory leak.
  // This way an instance can be garbage collected but we still have
  // access to its Priority value in order to make it available
  // for other Device instances.
  private static Dictionary<WeakReference<Device>, int> DeviceInstanceToIdMap { get; }
  private static Dictionary<int, int> DeviceIdToPriorityMap { get; }

  /* Instance members*/  

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  // CollectionView is used for sorting and filtering
  // the ComboBox binding source (the Priorities collection).
  // We also need a way to trigger the filter on the collection 
  // to remove priority values that are already taken.
  private ICollectionView AvailablePrioritiesCollectionView { get; }

  public ObservableCollection<int> AvailablePriorities { get; }
  public int Id { get; }
  public SensorType SensorType { get; }

  private int priority;
  public int Priority
  {
    get => this.priority;
    set
    {
      if (value == this.priority)
      {
        return;
      }

      if (!Device.PriorityValuePool.Contains(value))
      {
        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid priority. The value is already taken or out of bounds.");
      }

      int oldPriority = this.priority;
      this.priority = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
      OnPriorityChanged(oldPriority, value);
    }
  }

  static Device()
  {
    Device.PriorityValuePool = new HashSet<int>(Enumerable.Range(Device.LowerPriorityBound, Device.UpperPriorityBound));
    Device.DeviceInstanceToIdMap = new Dictionary<WeakReference<Device>, int>();
    Device.DeviceIdToPriorityMap = new Dictionary<int, int>();
  }

  protected Device(int deviceId, SensorType sensorType)
  {
    this.Id = deviceId;
    this.SensorType = sensorType;
    this.priority = -1;
    this.AvailablePriorities = new ObservableCollection<int>(Device.PriorityValuePool);
    this.AvailablePrioritiesCollectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.AvailablePriorities;
    this.AvailablePrioritiesCollectionView.Filter = FilterAvailablePriorityValues;
    ((ListCollectionView)this.AvailablePrioritiesCollectionView).CustomSort = Comparer<int>.Default;

    Device.DeviceInstanceToIdMap.Add(new WeakReference<Device>(this), this.Id);
  }

  private bool FilterAvailablePriorityValues(object obj)
    => obj is int priorityValue
         && (Device.PriorityValuePool.Contains(priorityValue) || priorityValue == this.Priority);

  private void OnPriorityChanged(int oldPriority, int newPriority)
  {
    // Make new value unavailable for other Device instances
    if (newPriority >= Device.LowerPriorityBound)
    {
      _ = Device.PriorityValuePool.Remove(newPriority);

      // Backup priority value so that we can make it available once the instance was garbage collected (destroyed)
      Device.DeviceIdToPriorityMap[this.Id] = newPriority;
    }

    // Make old value available for other Device instances
    OnPriorityValuePoolNewValueAvailable(oldPriority);
  }

  private void OnPriorityValuePoolNewValueAvailable(int oldPriority)
  { 
    if (oldPriority >= Device.LowerPriorityBound)
    {
      _ = Device.PriorityValuePool.Add(oldPriority);
    }

    Dictionary<WeakReference<Device>, int> deviceInstanceToIdMap 
      = new Dictionary<WeakReference<Device>, int>(Device.DeviceInstanceToIdMap);
    foreach (KeyValuePair<WeakReference<Device>, int> entry in deviceInstanceToIdMap)
    {
      WeakReference<Device> deviceInstanceReference = entry.Key;
      int deviceId = entry.Value;

      if (deviceInstanceReference.TryGetTarget(out Device? deviceInstance))
      {
        if (oldPriority >= Device.LowerPriorityBound
          && deviceInstance != this))
        {
          deviceInstance.AvailablePriorities.Add(oldPriority);
        }

        // Refresh to update removed and added priority values
        deviceInstance.AvailablePrioritiesCollectionView.Refresh();
      }

      // At this point the device instance no longer exists as it was already garbage collected
      else if (Device.DeviceIdToPriorityMap.TryGetValue(deviceId, out int feeDevicePriority))
      {
        _ = Device.DeviceInstanceToIdMap.Remove(deviceInstanceReference);
        _ = Device.DeviceIdToPriorityMap.Remove(deviceId);

        // Make deserted value available for other Device instances
        OnPriorityValuePoolNewValueAvailable(feeDevicePriority);
      }
    }
  }

  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    => this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

**TemperatureNode.cs**

```cs
public class TemperatureNode : Device
{
  public TemperatureNode(int deviceId) : base(deviceId, SensorType.Temperature)
  {
  }

  private double temperature;
  public double Temperature
  {
    get => this.temperature;
    set
    {
      this.temperature = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }
}
```

**HumidityNode.cs**

```cs
public class HumidityNode : Device
{
  public HumidityNode(int deviceId) : base(deviceId, SensorType.Humidity)
  {
  }

  private int humidity;
  public int Humidity
  {
    get => this.humidity;
    set
    {
      this.humidity = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }
}
```

**MainViewModel.cs**

```cs
class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  private Device selectedDevice;
  public Device SelectedDevice
  {
    get => this.selectedDevice;
    set
    {
      var oldSelectedDevice = this.selectedDevice;
      this.selectedDevice = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
      OnSelectedOrderChanged(oldSelectedDevice, value);
    }
  }
  

  private void OnSelectedOrderChanged(Device oldSelectedDevice, Device newSelectedDevice)
  {
    // TODO::Handle selected Device

    int selectedDevicePriority = newSelectedDevice.Priority;
    int deviceId = newSelectedDevice.Id;
    double temperature = ((TemperatureNode)newSelectedDevice).Temperature;
  }

  public ObservableCollection<Device> Devices { get; }

  public MainViewModel()
  {
    this.Devices = new ObservableCollection<Device>();

    for (int deviceId = 1; deviceId < 6; deviceId++)
    {
      var newTemperatureNode = new TemperatureNode(deviceId);
      newTemperatureNode.Temperature = deviceId + 20; ;
      newTemperatureNode.Priority = deviceId + 10;
      this.Devices.Add(newTemperatureNode);

      var newHumidityNode = new HumidityNode(++deviceId);
      newHumidityNode.Humidity = deviceId + 50;
      newHumidityNode.Priority = deviceId + 10;
      this.Devices.Add(newHumidityNode);
    }
  }

  private void OnSelectedOrderChanged(Order oldSelectedOrder, Order newSelectedOrder)
  {
    // TODO::Handle selected Order
  
    var selectedOrderItem = newSelectedOrder.SelectedOrderItem;
    var orderId = newSelectedOrder.Id;
  }

  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    => this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Now a device *has* a pool of avaibla priorities to choose from and an ID:

```cs
var items = device.AvailablePriorities;
var orderId = device.Id;
```

You should notice how the handling of a device has become more intuitive and natural.

Finally adjust your view:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window>
  <Window.DataContext>
    <MainViewModel />
  </Window.DataContext>

  <Window.Resources>
   
    <!-- Define DataTemplates for the ListView columns
         to display device subtype specific data -->

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TemperatureNode}">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Temperature, StringFormat={}{0}°C}" />
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:HumidityNode}">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Humidity, StringFormat={}{0}%}" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </Window.Resources>

  <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Devices}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDevice}">
    <ListView.View>
      <GridView>
        <GridViewColumn Header="ID"
                        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Id}" />
        <GridViewColumn Header="Priority">
          <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Device}">
              <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding AvailablePriorities}"
                        SelectedItem="{Binding Priority}" />
            </DataTemplate>
          </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn>

        <!-- "Reading" Column will automatically fetch the DataTemplate 
             from the Resources, depending on the current type.
             If you have more such columns you can define GridViewColumn.CellTemplateSelector 
             or use a DataGrid control instead of the ListView. -->
        <GridViewColumn Header="Reading" />

        <GridViewColumn Header="Sensor type"
                        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding SensorType}" />
      </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
  </ListView>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thank for your clearly explain about implement and compositon (since im a beginner, thats really help), im grateful but i think we don't get same point. I mean, i just want handle selected combobox in each row only (like get their selected value - without selected the row, only select the value in each combobox).

Comment: You had a row that represented an order. Each row had a ComboBox that hosted all IDs of all orders. This example has one order each row, where each order has an ID and a collection of items that make up the order. You can view and select the items of an order via the ComboBox. I think this is how data should be structured. It soesn't make sense that an order is associated with all order IDs. Of course you can keep your design and add a collection of IDs to the  Order  class - but why would you want this? That's a real question. Why do you want an Order to be associated with all order IDs?

Comment: You can't bind all ComboBoxes to the same source collection and track each selection individually. This doesn't scale - and it doesn't make sense. I gave you a good example how to improve your class design to solve your problem. If it makes sense or not: the gist of this example is to move the ID collection to the Order class, so that each ComboBox has its own source collection. Then bind the SelectedItem to the Order's SelectedItem. This way each row has its own selected item value. Just follow the example.

Comment: I see. I designed it like that because it relate to how my algorithm work on IoT device. But seem like i need change algorithm, or should create a database instead to track them individually, right?

Comment: You collect the data the way you do and generate the Order objects from it. I don't know how collect the data and how this data is structured. But you usually data is structured differently than the final entities. For example, this is the case for databases.

Comment: You didn't answer my questions. Why does an other have many IDs? This is a design mistake, isn't it?

Comment: If your algorithm that collects the data returns the data the way you were using it then you should redesign that too. Maker it return a useful or resolved data structure. A database can be overkill. Maybe a file database or a JSON file (with deserialization) - of you have to persist data. Otherwise your algorithm could return a proper order object. Your data structure must reflect the relationship of the data. Otherwise your code will become ugly and difficult very fast.

Comment: I first want when program onload, it will send a list include id and its order to all device in network (after encrypted data), to let them know their order to send data collected from environment (temperature, humidity or smth like that) back the program. The order should be able to change. The algorithm just bad since i read it from suggestion of someone in internet.

Comment: Many id because i have many device, each of them has its own id. but the network can only handle about 100 device, so only 100 order. I create much to test if the not allowed id join the network

Comment: Ah, now it's clearer. I really thought you were talking about a product order, like when a customer orders from a shop. This is a good example how context matters. My bad, I should have asked for more context. And your bad, because you should have provided that context in your question. So, order is the rank. The rank of a device. Luckily, my answer won't change in terms of class design. Just class name and properties would change. For example, you would have a class `Device` (instead of `Order`) and this `Device` would have a property `Rank` (or `Index`) and `Id`.

Comment: Very likely it would also have a property `IpAddress` to store the network address. Now you created more specialized classes that derive from `Device`, for example `ClimateDevice` that has a `Temperature` property etc. I hope you get the idea. Now when a device sends new data e.g., a new temperature reading, you simply update the `ClimateDevice.Temperature` property. And what was your original idea behind selecting an ID from the ComboBox?

Comment: My bad English, should use "priority" instead. The combobox was there if i wanna change the priority 1 - 100 of each device in network and send to the network new priority list while program communicating on next receiving.

Comment: But you said you wanted to bind IDs to the ComboBox (see you example). But it should be that ID is fixed and Priority can change (via ComboBox)?

Comment: The idea about `Device` class makes sense. I thought about that, but the path binding them make me struggle many days and i gave up. Should create an Interface for them since many kind of device, right?

Comment: Yeah, the id is fixed. The priority can change. Since only 2 column, i don't think reverse way not same.

Comment: Just name two devices as an example and I will update my answer to provide a more specific example. As I said, I would create an abstract base class `Device` and inherit more specialized devices from it.

Comment: `temperatureNode` and `humidityNode`, for example. 
Btw, the context u say the path fixed/change, u mean it should be synchronized? Like if i selected an id in a row, next combobox don't show the id again?

Comment: *" if i selected an id in a row, next combobox don't show the id again"* - yes we can do that. Makes totally sense. This we should implement in the base class so that all devices shre a common Priority pool. Wait, why are you always talking about IDs? ComboBox must show priorities? That's how I understood it.

Comment: Please verify my understanding: we have a list of devices, each row displays a device. Each row has a single ID, the ID of the device. Each device/row can select a priority 1-100 via a ComboBox. We have to filter the priority to prevent duplicates. Is that correct?

Comment: sr for late reply, i 've been tried a new algorithm and data structured but seems no help. Yes, i think no matter which fixed column, thats same my idea. U just give me concept, i will try to learn

Comment: I have updated the example. It's ready to use.

Comment: Please check the latest version. I fixed/improved some code. That's it.

Comment: That's a lot of information. Actually the path change list view to datagrid really help. I want row selected by default when i change only the combobox, but i used list view; while it is available in data grid. Dont worry anymore, u are my lifesaver.